# what would be a good way to calculate the current speed of an android?

Tags: android, gps

I am writing an android program that is a speedometer. the way it works wright now is it takes 2 GPS locations over time, and divides the distance by time to get speed. the problem with this is that it only refreshes when the gps moves, so when I stop moving it would stay at the last speed that I had. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Removed velocity tag because I don't think SO is doing meta tags anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of how long it is since you've had the last update, and adjust the speed after a certain amount of time has past. (You could use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to schedule the check).

In general gps is only going to give you a rough estimation of the speed though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Location object's speed estimate directly (check that it has one by calling `hasSpeed()`, then get it by calling `getSpeed()`).